# Qt Верстка основных компонентов программы

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Хочу разобраться как отобразить на сетке основные компоненты. В основном все показано на рисунке. Есть заголовок - верхняя часть программы, которая может растягиваться при изменении горизонтали. Есть основная часть формы(тоже гибкая, по центру), где уже отображено поле ввода текста и кнопка. Помогите разобраться, как поместить заголовок и основную часть в окно программы. [image]

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы хотите чтобы себя вели части окна - нужно ли пользователю менять размер боковых панелей, или они должны быть фиксированы, или растягиваться вместе с изменением размера окна

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, вертикаль фиксированная, а у горизонтали минимум растяжения от размера основной части.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов много. можно например так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>731</width>
    <height>450</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frameHeader">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: red</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item>
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>312</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Заголовок</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>312</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_Main">
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_left">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>1</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_Main">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>300</width>
          <height>300</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: blue</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_right">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>1</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>731</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это почти то, что мне нужно.